# How would I limit the user input() to only entering data once per day? I was thinking maybe the datetime stamp but unsure how to implement this

Tags: python, list, datetime, input, user-input

here is my code for retrieving the user input:

```
def inputQ1():
while True:
    try:
        Q1A = int(input("Rate your exercise today on scale 1-100: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("invalid value")
        continue
    else:
        return Q1A
```

and my code for recording the input into a list:

```
ansQ1 = []
ansQ1.append(inputQ1())
print(ansQ1)
```

how do I now ask for this user input again, just once per day?

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to close the program, and the data is still there?

Comment: yes plz, that would be useful too

Comment: My end goal is to have a programme that presents a graph to the client plotting the answers alongside each other in a graph day to day (probs using numpy, pandas, matplotlib for the visualisations for now)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datetime.datetime.now()`:

```
from datetime import datetime

def inputQ1():
    while True:
        try:
            Q1A = int(input("Rate your exercise today on scale 1-100: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("invalid value")
            continue
        else:
            return Q1A

dates = []
ansQ1 = []
while True:
    today = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    if today not in dates:
        ansQ1.append(inputQ1())
        dates.append(today)
        print(ansQ1)
```

Where `datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` returns the current date in the from of `2020-05-21`.

One thing to note, it isn't a very good practice to rely on `try` - `except` to convert an input into an `int`. Instead, use the `str.isdigit()` method:

```
def inputQ1():
    while True:
        Q1A = input("Rate your exercise today on scale 1-100: ")
        if Q1A.isdigit():
            return int(Q1A)
        print("invalid value")
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps. i've fixed all the try - except code into isdigit() method.

I have now implemented the datetime.now() and the code works fine but I'm unsure how to see if it's working or not, I want to only allow the user to enter input once a day